# What is the motivation behind RequireThis?

Tags: java, this, checkstyle, readability

[Checkstyle warns about RequireThis](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RequireThis)

Personally, I find it more readable (especially when reading not from IDE, but from code review tools, for example), but are there other reasons for this check beside readability?

Comment: It's explained right below the entry header.  *Checks that references to instance variables and methods of the present object are explicitly of the form "this.varName" or "this.methodName(args)" and that those references don't rely on the default behavior when "this." is absent.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just convention with some pros and cons.

This check is most useful if you do not use IDE. It may help for code review to disambiguate a code reference, improve readability and prevent confusion with local variable or parameter accesses.

On the other hand, most coding styles do not recommend using `this` everywhere, as this may be considered as unnecessary, redundant and too verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
int b,c;

public MyConstructor(int a, int b){
  b = a;
  c = b;
}
```

It's legal.  It compiles.  It probably doesn't do what you wanted it to.  Adding `this` makes sure that you don't accidentally shadow something you didn't mean to.

Comment: Thomas, yes, *always* in constructor everyone in the teams I was working with used this. The questions is maybe if it is a recommended practice, why in the class methods this is used so rarely, especially when invoking internal private methods, like callPrivateMethod(), instead of this.callPrivateMethod()